# Eclipse Tomcat Publishing Error: FlatFile Cannot be cast to IFlatFolder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, publishing

I have an application which I can't deploy or run in Tomcat because as soon as I attempt to start Tomcat in Eclipse (with this application configured in Add/Remove Project), I get this error:

```
Could not publish to the server.
org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.FlatFile cannot be cast to org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.flat.IFlatFolder
```

This happens on starting, publishing, and cleaning the Tomcat server in Eclipse, as long as my application is configured there. When I remove the application, I can publish fine.

What is this error about? I couldn't find any resources in Google.

Comment: Have you figured out what happened? I run into the same problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Check for '**org.eclipse.wst.common.component**' in your '**.settings**' folder in your maven project location. Check that the dependencies in that file are configured correctly. Make sure that a *file* (jar) is not added as a dependency at a placeholder for a *folder*.

I faced this issue when I added jar dependencies which were sibling modules to my project. I removed the 'dependency' tags and let maven configure the deployment descriptor for me automatically.

This worked for me and I cannot seem to find any other resource on google for this.